# iOS how to execute a task with beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios5, multitasking

I am trying to do two things for a simple test app.

I am stuck at trying to learn how to use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

I want to execute a backgroundTask when the user presses the home button (nothing fancy). In 9 minutes, I'd like to alert the user that the time is about to expire (if possible) and allow the user to switch back into the app to renew the 10 minutes.

I don't need backward compatibility with iOS 3, or 4.

Comment: Show us what code you have written to try this?

Comment: Well it will definitely not work on iOS 3 since it does not support background process. Also why do you want to support iOS 3?

Comment: I said I DON"T want to support iOS4 or iOS3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your code to continue in the background, then you'll need to wrap it in a background task. It's also very important that you call `endBackgroundTask` when you're finished - otherwise the app will be killed after it's allotted time has expired

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender

        [self beingBackgroundUpdateTask];

        // Do your long running background thing here

        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    });
}
- (void) beingBackgroundUpdateTask
{
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    }];
}

- (void) endBackgroundUpdateTask
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self.backgroundUpdateTask];
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

Comment: does the above code go in my application controller (MainViewController.m) or application delegate (AppDelegate.m)

Comment: Put this all in the view controller that has the button

Comment: Ashley, inside function "beingBackgroundUpdateTask" you are calling endBackgroundUpdateTask, and in function buttonPressed. you say to do the long running task in between, these two functions, so I dont get it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` function in your `UIApplicationDelegate`. You will need to set up a `UILocalNotification` and schedule it. You should also probably disable it in `applicationWillEnterForeground` so it doesn't fire off the user goes back to the app before it expires.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  UILocalNotification *timerNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  //set up notification with proper time and attributes
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:timerNotification];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

The cancelling code I gave there will actually cancel all notifications. If you have multiple notifications and only want to cancel a specific one, you should give the `userInfo` property of your notification a key/value when you set it up. Then, when the application enters the foreground, get the list of all active notifications by doing

`NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];`

and loop through them, checking `userInfo` until you get to the one you want and then just cancelling that one with

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:whateverNotification];`